# responsive image using css or material ui

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to make responsive image once the size becomes smaller it moves to bottom from the top right position. also I'm using material ui but can't find any help of it in this

```
.my-photo{
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
@media(max-width:800px){
    .my-photo{
        height: 250px;
      position: absolute;
        right:auto ;
        top: 500px;
        border-radius: 50%;

    }
}
```

Comment: Check `object-fit` property in CSS

Answer (score 0):

try using the `bottom` style:

```
.my-photo{
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


@media(max-width:800px){
    .my-photo{
        height: 250px;
        right: auto;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

plus try not to copy unnecessary styles in @media